# Django admin datetime `now` button picking correct local time, but wrong server time

Tags: python, django, time, nginx

Evening all,

When you click `now` on the Django admin DateTimeField picker widget, it fills in the current time with a little javascript.

However, my server is in UTC, and my client is in UTC+1 (British summer time, the most ironically named timezone).

So when I click `now`, I see 17:16 in the box. Which is **not** the correct time for now on the server, which is 16:16. So from my system's point of view, a model that is created now by the user, looks an hour old.

Is there a correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you [store all the data in UTC](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452353) and convert client side to the correct time for that timezone for display, and to UTC for storage?

Comment: Thanks Tim, we indeed store all dates as UTC (due to mysql limitations).

However it is the nature of this client-side conversion that I was interested in.
Anyone can throw together a fix (probably by overwriting the model's `save()` method and tweaking the django admin form, but I was hoping  there might be a "right" way to do this, maybe even a Django way.

Answer (score 0):

The way I propose it might work is by using the server time, as served by the [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript):

`Date: fri, 19 apr 2013 16:16:00 gmt`

However, that gets less correct the longer the page is open, so it's not a very good answer...